# Import my LinkedIn employment and education information into my ORCID iD profile

Tags: research, linkedin, orcid

I'm looking for a program, browser extension or userscript that can import my LinkedIn employment and education information into my  ORCID iD profile. The import could be done either on request (e.g. click) or automatically whenever I start the browser / start the computer / etc.

Any price, OS, license and browser is fine.

Comment: I haven't found any program so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.